# How to prevent hidden element to be shown when focused in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, focus, overflow, css-position

I have a strange problem today, in Chrome, when I focus on an element that is absolutely positioned out of its overflow hidden container, it gets visible in Chrome browser (Mac).

I've made a fiddle to illustrate the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/GHgtc/

**Html**

```
    <div id="container">
        <a id="inner-button" href="#">You can see me !</a>
    </div>
```

**Css**

```
#container{
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#inner-button{
    display: block;
    background: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: -20px;
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Cheers !

Comment: OK, this is creepy...

Comment: Even if you use `#inner-button:focus{ right:-40px;}` it will become visible whet it'll lose focus.

Comment: For the info, the same applies to FF too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use tabindex="-1" on your "inner-button". That will prevent focus.
http://jsfiddle.net/GHgtc/2/

```
<input placeholder="focus on me then press tab" type="text">
<div id="container">
    <a id="inner-button" tabindex="-1" href="#">You can see me !</a>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

I realized there is another possible solution to your issue while working on some focus issue of my own. You can use z-index:-1 if the focus you need is to be triggered later via javascript event.

```
#inner-button{
    display: block;
    background: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: -20px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GHgtc/3/

That will keep it focusable but hidden. And you can make it visible back with z-index:0 dynamically.

Comment: Hi, yes, I came to work with that solution, but it prevents focus and that is unwanted. The problem is how to keep the focus available without this strange side-effect...

Comment: Ah well. An anchor link is gonna focus if you tab to it, that's an accessibility related behavior required for screen readers or 'keyboard only' navigation. It's actually normal. It just seems that Safari only shows it with universal access assistance on... If you want to hide that inner-button until another event occurs, how about hiding it first with visibility: hidden; ? Your position: absolute; method is technically not hiding that button at the moment. Only visibility:hidden; or display:none; will actually hide it when focused. i.e. A focused link will alway show for accessibility reason.