# Prevent scrolling to :focused button

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, accessibility

*The following problem does not apply to Firefox. It does, however, apply to Chromium, (some?) versions of IE, Vivaldi, etc.*

While working on a simple [website](http://www.evangelismmission.com) for a friend's missions organization, I came upon a problem with the home page slideshow. The slideshow's basic layout and styling follow:

**html**

```
<div id="JSslideshow">
    [... images ...]
    <button id="ssprev" type="button" data-para="-1"></button>
    <button id="ssnext" type="button" data-para="1"></button>
</div>
```

**css**

```
/*Setup javascript slideshow*/
#JSslideshow {
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #005;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    }

    /*setup the slideshow button general rules*/
    button {
        background-image: url('../data/home/arrows.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: 2px solid white;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 64px;
        margin-top: -32px;
        opacity: .75;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: 64px;
        }

    #ssnext {
        background-position: 0px -64px;
        border-radius: 25% 0px 0px 25%;
        margin-right: -32px;
        right: -2px;
        }

    #ssprev {
        background-position: 0px 0px;
        border-radius: 0px 25% 25% 0px;
        left: -2px;
        margin-left: -32px;
        }
```

If you tab to the last button in the slideshow, everything slides to the left so that the last button is fully visible. (Remember: This doesn't apply to Firefox.)

Example:

*Correct!*
[image: correct look]

turns into

[image: bad look]
*Wrong!*

Finally deciding to ask the opinion of my fellow stackoverflow users, I decided to get a minimal, verifiable, JSFiddle example.

[Here it is.](https://jsfiddle.net/welcome_me/kc5dx5av/) (Note how the text slides to the left whenever you tab to the last button.)

[This one,](https://jsfiddle.net/welcome_me/z4tfyhdw/) however, works properly.

The difference between the 2?

```
#ssnext {
        right: -2px; /*This is 0px in the example that works correctly*/
        }
```

Does anyone have *any* idea why `right: -2px` makes the `#JSSlideshow` div scroll to the focused `#next` button?

### **Note 1:**

As you can see in the comments below, @sherrifderek believes that `right: -2px;` isn't the root of the problem. It probably isn't, but it does **fix** the problem.

Does anyone have anymore ideas?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the 2px. Look at this stripped down CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/6gngrxbg/1/

Comment: @sheriffderek: Ok. I notice that your example doesn't have the problem I was facing; however, it still doesn't explain why I have the issue I do or why one fiddle works and the other one doesn't ... ?

Comment: Well, either way - no one uses Vivaldi... so I wouldn't use that to test. The issue is definitely whatever the default 'focus' state does to ensure your button is visible... and it scoots over the div for some reason. Nothing in the console about that. Nothing to do with a slider. you could have a test case more like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/91fLt97a/

Comment: @sherrifderek: True story (about vivaldi); however, the same issue is apparent with chromium and people **do** use that. (That's what I'm currently testing on.) It's not a huge issue and no one tabs to buttons anyways, so the only reason I asked this question is because I want to know *why* it works the way it does.

Comment: I agree that we should understand why this works the way it does. I do think, however - that you should forget about the 2px and the slider, if you want to get to the real root of this. It's clouding the subject.

Comment: @sheriffderek: Sorry, I still don't understand what you are trying to say. What do you mean by 'slider'? Also, I'm a little lost as to why the '2px' is not the real root of this?

Comment: I don't have the 2px or most of your code in my example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/91fLt97a/, and the ghost is still pushing things over. Start looking in this direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091292/how-to-prevent-hidden-element-to-be-shown-when-focused-in-chrome

Comment: @sheriffderek: Thanks for the suggestion. However, the intention is to allow that button to *remain* focusable. The answer to the supplied question involves preventing the button from being focusable. Again, this does not occur on Firefox.

Comment: I'm not saying to hide it / I'm just saying that you need to be looking for `accessibility` bug cases - and `overflow hidden` and `focus` ~ and not to worry about your code or your CSS. The 2px has nothing to do with anything. and that this title "'right: -2px' on button “scrolls” 'overflow: hidden' div" isn't going to get much attention. Look at my last example, and you'll see that the same problem that you are describing is there when you tab. Good luck! ~ can't chat right now. Gotta go. : )